# Toggle focus to follow toggleClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm doing a simple show/hide on a search form that uses jQuery's `toggleClass()` and CSS to show and hide the form. That's easy enough, something like:

```
$('#site-search-toggle').click(function(e){
    $('#site-search').toggleClass('search-open');
    e.preventDefault()
});
```

What I'd like to do but am having a hard time figuring out is to put focus on the search input when the form is shown and remove the focus from the search input when the form is hidden.

It's easy to add focus:

```
$('#site-search-toggle').click(function(e){
    $('#site-search').toggleClass('search-open');
    $('#site-search input[type="search"]').focus();
    e.preventDefault()
});
```

But I'm stuck at how to remove it when `$('#site-search-toggle')` is clicked again to hide the form.

Comment: set focus somewhere else or use `.blur()` to cause the element to lose focus.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn is right .. and if .blur() not work .. use trigger('click') on any other element

Comment: @JonathanKuhnm how would I sync that with the toggleClass behavior, though, so that then the form is shown the field is focused, and when it is hidden it is not focused?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I figured this one out, or at least I found a way to do what I need to do. I added a second class, `search-closed`, toggled both classes, then used each class to focus or blur the field, something like this:

```
$('#site-search').addClass('search-closed');

$('.site-search__toggle').click(function(e){
    // toggle both classes
    $('#site-search').toggleClass('search-open search-closed');

    // set focus when form is visible, .search-open
    // use setTimeout to make sure the cursor actually gets in there
    // don't know why, but it works
    setTimeout (function(){
        $('#site-search.search-open .site-search__input').focus();
    }, 20);

    // blur when the form is not visible, .search-closed
    $('#site-search.search-closed .site-search__input').blur();

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just found this thread as I've been banging my head against this problem for a while now.

I've found a very simple way to do this, and essentially all you need to do is provide a click handler. When the element is clicked, you toggle the class which controls the 'focused' state, but you also programatically focus the element:

```
document.getElementById('myelement').addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.classList.toggle('focus'); // or whatever...
    this.focus();
});
```

You will need to give the element some sort of 'tabindex' value, probably 0 or -1.

And then, you provide a 'blur' handler, which just removes the 'focus' class whenver the user navigates away from the element.

```
document.getElementById('myelement').addEventListener('blur', function() {
    this.classList.remove('focus');
    return false;
});
```

Works like a dream!

I'm sorry that this is not a jQuery answer, but it should be easy enough to adapt - I just don't use it...

Danny

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#site-search-toggle').click(function(e){
$('#site-search').toggleClass('search-open');
if ($('#site-search').hasClass('search-open')) {
    $('#site-search input[type="search"]').focus();
} else {
    $('#site-search input[type="search"]').blur();
}
e.preventDefault();
});
```